# Is there a way to force mutate in R to use single values rather than whole column values?

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

For example, I have tried:

```
df <- tibble(x = c(1,0,0,1), y = c(1,1,0,0), z = c(0,1,1,0))
df <- df %>% mutate(pos_seq = c(x,y,z))
#or
df <- df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(pos_seq = c(x,y,z))
```

both of which give errors due to different sizes.

And I have tried:

```
df <- tibble(x = c(1,0,0,1), y = c(1,1,0,0), z = c(0,1,1,0))
df <- df %>% mutate(pos_seq = list(c(x,y,z)))
#or
df <- df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(pos_seq = list(c(x,y,z)))
```

which makes pos_seq a list of the full x column, y column, z column, not just the single row values.

Same problem when I use a different way of 'aggregating' x/y/z e.g. `mutate(pos_str = paste((x,y,z), collapse = ""))`. I'm not understanding why something like `sum()` works on single row values, but other functions don't. Can I force it?

I want this result:

| x | y | z | pos_seq | pos_str |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | c(1,1,0) | "110" |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | c(0,1,1) | "011" |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | c(0,0,1) | "001" |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | c(1,0,0) | "100" |

In reality, I am wanting to run a complex function on a dataset that needs to take multiple variables from the row and use them, including characters and vectors, and some of these decisions rely on aggregates like "pos_seq" or "pos_str".
But this demo seems to be the stem of my problems.

Comment: Not sure why the table hasn't formatted correctly here - it looks fine in edit preview (sorry!)

Comment: May have found my answer: `df <- df %>% rowwise() %>% plyr::mutate(pos_seq = list(c(x,y,z)))`, which doesn't work here, has different behaviour to `df <- df %>% rowwise() %>% dplyr::mutate(pos_seq = list(c(x,y,z)))`, which does work here, which may explain why my function was working before but not today (after reinstalling packages due to another problem). I will leave my question as an answer on how to force `plyr::mutate()` to do this at all or `dplyr::mutate()` to do this without `rowwise()` will still be helpful?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `list` and `c` in combination with `rowwise` for your pos_seq column and use `paste0` with `collapse` to create one string of the values for your pos_str column like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
df <- tibble(x = c(1,0,0,1), y = c(1,1,0,0), z = c(0,1,1,0))
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(pos_seq = list(c(x,y,z)),
         pos_str = paste0(pos_seq, collapse = ""))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 5
#> # Rowwise: 
#>       x     y     z pos_seq   pos_str
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <list>    <chr>  
#> 1     1     1     0 <dbl [3]> 110    
#> 2     0     1     1 <dbl [3]> 011    
#> 3     0     0     1 <dbl [3]> 001    
#> 4     1     0     0 <dbl [3]> 100
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, I added an edit to indicate I did try this too, and also wasn't getting the result I wanted. Seems to be a difference with `plyr::mutate` (which I was using inadvertently) and `dplyr::mutate`. Any explanation for the difference in behaviour?

Comment: @ChrisP, the main difference is that `plyr::mutate` can be applied to lists, but `dplyr::mutate` is faster. I would suggest to use `dplyr`.

Answer (score 1):

Her a one-liner that does the job.

```
cbind(df, list2DF(list(pos_seq=apply(df, 1, list))), pos_str=Reduce(paste0, df))
#   x y z pos_seq pos_str
# 1 1 1 0 1, 1, 0     110
# 2 0 1 1 0, 1, 1     011
# 3 0 0 1 0, 0, 1     001
# 4 1 0 0 1, 0, 0     100
```